# Ugly expression. Cant tell if I can simplify. Is there a general method for simplifying basic algebraic expressions?

Tags: transcendental-equations

Let $\rho, \omega, c > 0$ and let $\alpha \in [0,1]$. I have managed to calculate

\begin{align*}
\frac{\rho}{\alpha x^{\alpha-1}y^{1-\alpha}}&= \eta\\
\frac{\omega}{(1-\alpha) x^{\alpha}y^{-\alpha}}&= \eta\\
\left(\frac{\rho}{\omega} \frac{1-\alpha}{\alpha}\right)^{\alpha-1}c &= x \\ 
 \left(\frac{\rho}{\omega} \frac{1-\alpha}{\alpha}\right)^{\alpha}c &=y\\
\end{align*}

So I obviously tried plugging in. But this lead me to a really ugly expression:

\begin{align*}
\eta&=\frac{\rho}{\alpha 
\left(\left(\frac{\rho}{\omega} \frac{1-\alpha}{\alpha}\right)^{\alpha-1}c\right)
^{\alpha-1}
\left(\left(\frac{\rho}{\omega} \frac{1-\alpha}{\alpha}\right)^{\alpha}c\right)
^{1-\alpha}}\\
&= \frac{\rho}{\alpha 
\left(\frac{\rho}{\omega} \frac{1-\alpha}{\alpha}\right)^{(2\alpha-1)(\alpha-1)}
}\\
\end{align*} 
**My Question:**

(1) How can I simplify this?

(2) Is there a general method for how to simplify an arithmetic expression? I seem to have a lot of these formulas that are quite complicated and it would be nice if there were some other way besides trial and error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you made a mistake in your calculation. The correct answer will be
$$\eta=\frac{\rho}{\alpha 
\left(\frac{\rho}{\omega} \frac{1-\alpha}{\alpha}\right)^{\color{red}{1-\alpha}}}.
$$
I don't know if you think this is simple.

Answer (score 1):

Let $\frac{\rho}{\omega}(1/\alpha-1)=a$, then, you have $x=a^{\alpha-1}c,\ y=a^\alpha c$. So, $$\eta=\frac{\rho}{\alpha a^{1-\alpha}}=\frac{\omega a^\alpha}{1-\alpha}$$

Answer (score 0):

Try looking at $x/y$. I note that you first two equations involve $x/y$. Set $z=x/y$ and then use the third and fourth equations to deduce

$$z = \frac{\omega}{\rho}\frac{\alpha}{1-\alpha}$$

Equation 1 and 2 become

$$\eta = \frac{\omega}{(1-\alpha) z^{\alpha}}$$

And

$$\eta = \frac{\rho}{\alpha z^{(\alpha-1)}}$$

So

$$\eta = \frac{\omega}{(1-\alpha)(\frac{\omega\alpha}{\rho(1-\alpha)})^{\alpha}}$$

And therefore

$$\eta = \frac{\rho^\alpha(1-\alpha)^{(\alpha-1)}}{(\omega^{(\alpha-1)}\alpha^\alpha)}$$